# regexp to capitalize every first letter of every word and ignore some

Tags: c#, regex

hey guys how i can create a regexp to capitalize every first letter of every word and ignore some words like: dos, de, da.

i want a string like this: "TEMporADA DOS TECNologoS"

to be: "Temporada dos Tecnologos".

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a list of all the words you want ignored?  That is not something you can define a set or general rules for ...

Comment: regex might not be particularly necesary, you can have a `string[]` of words you want to ignore, then split the given string, ("*Temporada dos Tecnologos*") in this case, by spaces. You may then set them all to lowercase and then check if each word is in the array, if not you can set the first letter to uppercase. After this you can join them all with a space and voila

Comment: can you say words smaller than 3 length guarantee to start lowercase?

Comment: The word to be ignored is:
do, de, dos, das, e

Comment: Well, you haven't ignored `dos` because you have modified `DOS` to `dos`. What rules apply?

Answer (score 2):

No regex needed. You could first use [`TextInfo.ToTitleCase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase(v=vs.110).aspx) and then apply the lowercase rule(you have changed DOS to dos) on the "ignore"-words:

```
string text = "TEMporADA DOS TECNologoS";
string[] ignoreWords = {"dos", "de", "da"};

text = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(text); // uppercase first letter all
var newWords = text.Split()
    .Select(w => ignoreWords.Contains(w, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
                   ? Char.ToLower(w[0]) + w.Substring(1) 
                   : w);
text = String.Join(" ", newWords);
```

Comment: Pretty much what I would have written, +1